# Evince 3.10 with menubar

Tags: unity, gtk3, evince

I find that the 2 buttoms menu from  the  evince v3.10.0 are  not really useful.
Why did ubuntu NOT re add an menubar?. It would have been looking better in unity !
The unity top panel has enough space for an normal program menu.
Here is an screenshot of what i mean:

(The program works already in ubuntu 13.10 with unity or cinnamon fine.
Some little compiler warnings but nothing more)
Example in Cinnamon
[image: Example in cinnamon]

or in unity

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The menu items are in the top right corner. I'm attaching a pic of that.

[image: Options in Evince]

Comment: Yes, they are but other gnome 3 applications like eog have still the old menu. I search still the menubar , even if evince normally  doesn't have one. I mean  that unity has something like a top panel, so why not use it!

Comment: Honestly I've no ideas about it :(

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that there is no such option anymore. which is likely as you can clearly see that Ubuntu has been removing many settings from many application in recent years. That is just their philosophy (which I am strongly against - since this over-simplicity crashes usability).

Anyway, there is no sign of toolbar in manpage.
You can also see yourself in dconf-editor

> org.gnome.Evince

that here is key "show-toolbar", but is does not do anything anymore.

I miss the toolbar too. :-(

Guess we have to learn keyboards shortcuts.

Comment: Patch for the menubar here: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=161336. Have also an evince 3.7.1 compiled for ubuntu 13.10 with some code fragments from the 3.10 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's seems to be no menubar anymore [see here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.apps.evince.general/2151).
Clearly a weird strategy, I hope developpers will change their mind if we keep complaining.

Comment: Fixed in 14.04 at least in gnome-session-flashback (finally)! Will fix file-roller and epiphany from 14.04 soon too and send the patch to launchpad!